# How can I add extra CFLAGS for sources under specific directories?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-warnings

I am currently porting some huge (100k+ LOC, dozens of modules) project from running under CentOS 7 to running in Ubuntu 22.

This project depends on certain old code from third parties that for compatibility reasons cannot be modified or updated (would generate ridiculous amounts of work across a stack that 5 teams work on).

Having a newer version of gcc means a lot more warnings than before, meaning that we can't use -Werror without disabling those warnings. I'd like to disable the specific warnings but only for the particular modules.

The project is structured in one top level Makefile and then multiple module.mk files inside different directories that append to the SRC of the top level Makefile. I want to be able to pass some extra cflags only for the compilation of sources under specific modules

My solution

I currently went withusing bitbake-style postfixes for CFLAGS and using `dir` on the target source to get the correct variable (expanding a variable to use as a variable name). What are the downsides of this? Is there a better way to do it (like filtering in the target names)?

Here is an example of the current solution (pretend flags and modules)

```
# before this all the cross compiling vars are set (CC, LD,...)
MODULES := comm/digest comm/gsoap filters

include $(patsubst %,%/module.mk,$(MODULES))

CFLAGS := -Werror
CFLAGS_comm/gsoap/ := -Wno-unused-result

OBJ = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))

all: $(OBJ)
    echo "just example"

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_$(dir $*.c)) -o $@ $*.c
```

Comment: This is not easy to answer unless there was probably more information. But I suggest you try and replace the whole build system. It would probably be easier.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, I take the OP to be saying that the approach they have presented works (which I find plausible).  If that's so, then in what way would replacing the build system be easier?

Comment: It works but it has some issues. First of all it doesn't work for subdirectories. In the example if a source file is inside `comm/gsoap/extra` for example it won't work.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to just have two different targets, one of which is for %.o only when the files are under a specific dir and another one for the rest

Comment: @TomásÁlvarez if you know better a different tool, like `cmake` or `autotools` then that's what I am suggesting. Building projects consisnting of just C files is not hard, so you can try that. And also these have more flexibility and can help you set up the exact scenario that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the downsides of this?

- It isn't working for me (the inner function call in the variable reference is not being expanded to form part of the name of the outer variable reference).  That it's working for you probably indicates a `make`-version dependency that could be an issue for you.
- As you observe in comments, the extra flags are tied to a specific directory, not a whole subtree.
- The build recipe is more cryptic than usual.
- Variable names with slashes in them are prone to confusing people (though `make` itself doesn't mind).
- I presume that you intend to put the per-module `CFLAGS` definitions in the `module.mk` files, but if you were to instead put them directly in the `Makefile`, as shown, then that would break your modularity.

> Is there a better way to do it (like filtering in the target names)?

I guess it depends on your criteria for "better".  One alternative would be to provide more specific pattern rules in the `module.mk` files that need them.  For example:

**comm/digest/module.mk**

```
# ...

comm/digest/%.o: comm/digest/%.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -extra -flags -o $@ $<

# ...
```

This works because `make` will prefer the more specific rule over the general one for targets that the former matches.  That should also make it cover whole subtrees (except where further overridden at deeper levels).

If you prefer, you can still create per-module variables for the additional flags, but your choice of names for them is no longer constrained other than by the need to avoid collisions.